# How do I declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header using rack-cors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cors, rack-cors

In order to access my api from frontend it is asking I declare Content-Range in the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. I can't figure out exactly how to write it.

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'

    resource '*',
      headers: ["Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Range: 0-24/319"], 
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

or

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any, 
      expose: ["Content-Range: orders 0-24/319"],
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

Any idea what I've written incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

according to [test case](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors/blob/dbea904a7767aef89f48686635add60157144d42/test/unit/test.ru#L20) in original repo
there is no possibility to pass `key: value` pair inside routes definition
that would be accepted by rack-cors

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any, 
      expose: ["Content-Range"],
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

and then for example, you can write default value in `BaseController` and then inherit every controller from it

```rb
class BaseController < ApplicationController
  after_action :apply_content_range_header

  protected
  def apply_content_range_header
    response.headers['Content-Range'] = 'orders 0-24/319'
  end
end
```

and then in your controller just call it

```rb
class ProductsController < BaseController
  def index; end # your products#index will have Content-Range header
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Will try out!

Comment: normally you should inherit `BaseController` from `ApplicationController`, and all you other controllers like `ProductsController` from `BaseController`, I will update the answer

Comment: Thank you. Works perfect. I really appreciate it!